# Changing Oracle TRUNC to ANSI EXTRACT on a DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use ANSI standard syntax. The current code uses Oracle's proprietary TRUNC. The ANSI standard EXTRACT only gets one (1) element at a time. Is the code below the only way to emulate TRUNC in ANSI standard syntax? Is there a better way?

```
AHOST (AUSER): SELECT
  2      TRUNC(TO_DATE('1998-03-07', 'RRRR-MM-DD'))
  3      ,TO_DATE(
  4          EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '1998-03-07')
  5          || '-'
  6          || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '1998-03-07')
  7          || '-'
  8          || EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE '1998-03-07')
  9          ,'RRRR-MM-DD'
 10      )
 11  FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(TO_ TO_DATE(E
--------- ---------
07-MAR-98 07-MAR-98
```

Comment: Trying to use ANSI standard for handling dates is probably not really possible.  Don't bother.  For instance, `to_date()` is not standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I would have an actual DATE or DATETIME field and would not be using TO_DATE(). The core problem is Oracle's non-standard inclusion of a timestamp in the DATE type. Isn't there a better way to have code that can be migrated to other platforms without editing and testing?

Comment: What you try to do using `EXTRACT` will not work as you concat integers returned by `EXTRACT`and not strings, there's no automatic cast from numeric to string in ANSI (and day/month might miss the leading zero causing errors, too). The ANSI Standard for truncating the time portion of a timestamp would be `CAST(timestamp_column AS DATE)`, but this will obviously not work in Oracle :-)

Comment: If the complaint is that a DATE has a timestamp contrary to ANSI standard, then two options: 1) If the time serves no business purpose then TRUNC() the value on insert/update via trigger. 2) If it has business value then slap a view on top of the table that provides both a TRUNC() version of the field and another version cast to TIMESTAMP() to keep an ANSI standards with and without timestamp, and then code through the view. But really you're just making work (and headaches) for yourself for the sake of style if you are chucking out all Oracle built-ins and giving up what they have to offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are concerned about portability of code, then you have a lot of concerns. You will need to start creating user-defined functions to handle basic tasks, and then define these functions in any database you want to port to. Happily, in most cases, the functions are pretty easy to design.

The harder part is ensuring that your code base *only* uses these functions and not other features of the language.

Developing database-agnostic SQL code probably isn't a worthy goal anyway. You might want to develop a formal API between your application and the database, and then consciously re-implement this API in each database -- along with a testing suite.

After all, something as simple as `select 1/2` returns vastly different results in different databases (0, 0.5, and syntax error come to mind).

Answer (score 0):

Date formatting is a question of changing the *appearance* of the date. The only way to do that is to generate a string.

Given that, there is a `to_char` function which does just that. As far as I can tell, and I can’t find a definitive answer, it’s in the ANSI standard. It is certainly supported by Oracle, PostgreSQL and Teradata, and presumably others which claim ANSI support.

To the the result in your sample:

```sql
select to_char(current_timestamp,'DD-MON-YY')
from dual;
--  26-JUL-22
```